# How to get the list of all the weeks in a particular year using jquery or rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a requirement where i have to populate drop down with list of all the weeks in a particular year as shown in the image

[image]

How can i achieve the list dynamically depending on the year using jquery or Rails?

Answer (score 1):

```
    start_date = Date.current.beginning_of_year
    end_date = Date.current.end_of_year
    weeks = []
    (start_date..end_date).to_a.in_groups_of(7).each do |range|
         weeks << "#{range.first} to #{range.last}"
    end
```

Comment: In case if you need array in some other way. you just need to change this line
        weeks << [range.first,range.last]

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
date1 = Date.today.beginning_of_year
date2 = Date.today.end_of_year
weeks = []
while date2>date1 do
    weeks << [date1.beginning_of_week, date1.end_of_week]
    date1=date1+7.days
end
```

You can also format date as per your requirement before pushing it to array.

Answer (score -1):

```
function getDaysInMonth(month, year) {
     // Since no month has fewer than 28 days
     var date = new Date(year, month, 1);
     var days = [];
     console.log('month', month, 'date.getMonth()', date.getMonth())
     while (date.getMonth() === month) {
        days.push(new Date(date));
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
     }
     return days;
}
```